# Глобальные константы в Django

Tags: django

Всем привет!

Перехожу с богомерзкого php на великолепный python.
Как следствие осваиваю django :)

И вот есть вопрос: хочу хранить путь к каталогу проекта как глобальную переменную (код из файла settings.py)

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.normpath(os.path.abspath(PROJECT_ROOT))
```

При попытке вызвать оную константу из файла app/modules.py получаю:

> NameError: name 'PROJECT_ROOT' is not
> defined

Умные дяди, подскажите маленькому: как хранить глобальные константы?

Comment: код вызова пожалуйста покажите, settings.py - подключен?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С точки зрения безопасности глобальные переменные - плохая идея. В то же время вы всегда можете использовать

```
from proj_name.settings import your_var
```

Это позволит разделять пространство имён и использовать удобные для Вас переменные в нужном месте.

Comment: Спасибо. Усе понил!

Answer (score 2):

```
from django.conf.settings import PROJECT_ROOT
```

Comment: Модуль config, которого не было?

**from django.conf import settings**